# changing the style of an element after certain condition on another page is met

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

I have a link to a video in my html code that when users click on it, it will open in a new tab. what I want to do is that, when a user watched the whole video (or half of it), then the link style on the first page would change (for example changing its color). But if the user does not watch the whole video , I don't want anything happens to the link style in the first page. How can I do that with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to set a variable in `localstorage` or `sessionstorage` (depending on how long you want the effect to last). You would essentially have to add a key to `localstorage` at the end of the video being played, and then change the style of all links on the sending page based on the current state of `localstorage`.

However, this seems really complicated and unnecessary, and I think the complexity may be an indicator of a user experience smell. It would be helpful if you could offer more information regarding how you will be playing the videos and why it's important that the user are able to see this from the link itself.

Comment: I think they have a simpler use case than what I gathered from your original question. If you look at the DOM structure, the colored part of the link is actually a different DOM element inside of the link, and is almost certainly being rendered at the server level. Meaning they're saving that you've finished the video, and determining which icon to place as the page is rendered.

Comment: well It is best to look at the following example:

https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-equations/first-order-differential-equations

Here on khanacademy website, when you watch a course (video) and then go back to the original page (which shows the list of content) you can see that the little circle next to the course title is turned to blue. But if you don't watch the whole video the circle color does not change. This way you can know which courses you have watched and which you have not. I want to obtain the similar effect. I don't know if that helps :)

Comment: See my comment above this one; adding this so you don't miss it.

Comment: I see. So I need server side programming which I don't know anything about it :) Thank you very much Nathan. It really helped. At least now I know that I can't do it with just JavaScript.